# How do I set the option panel of dcc components in plotly dash to always display outside the div containing the dcc component

Tags: plotly-dash

I am working on a web app using plotly dash. below is the  app's layout:

```
`import dash 
from dash import html, dcc 

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

value = range(20)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='picker',
        start_date='01-10-2022',
        end_date='01-08-2022',
        display_format='DD-MM-YY'
    ),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown1',
        options=[{'label':val,'value':val} for val in value]
    ),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown2',
        options=[{'label':val,'value':val} for val in value]
    ),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown3',
        options=[{'label':val,'value':val} for val in value]
    ),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown4',
        options=[{'label':val,'value':val} for val in value]
    ),
     dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown5',
        options=[{'label':val,'value':val} for val in value]
    ),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown6',
        options=[{'label':val,'value':val} for val in value]
        ),
    ],id='controls')
], id='main_container')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)`
```

and below is the stylesheet:

```
`body{
    margin: 5%;
    background-color: aquamarine;
 }
 #main_container{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
 }
#controls{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width:15rem;
    height: 15rem;
    gap: 1.5rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    background-color: rgb(3, 20, 20);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}`
```

Although this is not the project, want I am aiming is similar to what is described here.
The dcc components with the controls div all have their option panels inside the div containing them because of the `overflow-y: scroll;` property. I want the option panels to always display outside the div containing the dcc components.

I tried to set the z-index value to higher value but I am unable to find the default className of  the option panel